# when running yarn install, what does it mean when a module doesn't provide another?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

when i run `yarn` on my react app that uses firebase, i will get several warnings like...

```sh
@firebase/auth@npm:0.14.5 [c52f6] doesn't provide @firebase/app-types@0.x requested by @firebase/auth-types@npm:0.10.0

myapp@workspace:. doesn't provide @testing-library/dom@>=5 requested by @testing-library/user-event@npm:10.2.0
```

(fyi... i am using yarn v2)

does this mean i need to explicitly add those to my package.json?

Comment: Go through this, https://dev.to/arcanis/implicit-transitive-peer-dependencies-ed0

This blog post defines very clearly.

Comment: @AshutoshKumar - That blog only addresses the first warning, and only if the OP is the author of `@firebase/auth`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error code for this is YN0002, see the [official documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/error-codes#yn0002---missing_peer_dependency) explaining this error.

It is regarding [peer-dependencies](https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/) which are dependencies that are typically loaded with another dependency (its peer) at a specific version.

In summary, this is an error that can only be fixed by the package author. As an end-user, you won't be able to apply any of the recommendations as mentioned in the official documentation.

Answer (score 4):

As an update to the top answer, it is fixable with `yarn` packageExtensions. You can manually declare a package with another dependency/peerependency in the `yarnrc.yml` file.

https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#packageExtensions

ex:

```
@testing-library/user-event@*:
    dependencies:
        @firebase/app-types: "^0.x.x"
```

or

```
@testing-library/user-event@*:
    peerDependenciesMeta:
        @firebase/app-types:
            optional: true
```