# Error setting up redux toolkit for local development

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I've been trying to get the redux toolkit setup for local development and have been running into issues. I'm trying to setup the toolkit project under the packages/toolkit directory. When I try to run `yarn install` nothing is installed in the `node_modules` folder and below is the output from the terminal:

```
➤ YN0000: ┌ Project validation
➤ YN0057: │ @examples-query-react/graphql-codegen: Resolutions field will be ignored
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0002: │ @chakra-ui/accordion@npm:1.0.0 [1a614] doesn't provide framer-motion (pf3894), requested by @chakra-ui/transition
➤ YN0002: │ @chakra-ui/hooks@npm:1.0.0 [1a614] doesn't provide react-dom (p7fdf8), requested by @reach/auto-id
➤ YN0002: │ @chakra-ui/modal@npm:1.0.0 [1a614] doesn't provide react-dom (p700d9), requested by @chakra-ui/portal
➤ YN0002: │ @chakra-ui/popover@npm:1.0.0 [1a614] doesn't provide react-dom (p50155), requested by @chakra-ui/portal
➤ YN0002: │ @chakra-ui/react@npm:1.0.0 [4f028] doesn't provide react-dom (p0de17), requested by @chakra-ui/portal
➤ YN0002: │ @chakra-ui/react@npm:1.0.0 [4f028] doesn't provide react-dom (p55a3d), requested by @chakra-ui/toast
➤ YN0002: │ @chakra-ui/skeleton@npm:1.0.0 [1a614] doesn't provide @chakra-ui/theme (p91f15), requested by @chakra-ui/media-query
➤ YN0002: │ @chakra-ui/skeleton@npm:1.0.0 [1a614] doesn't provide @emotion/react (p906ad), requested by @chakra-ui/system
➤ YN0002: │ @chakra-ui/skeleton@npm:1.0.0 [1a614] doesn't provide @emotion/styled (p9ee07), requested by @chakra-ui/system
➤ YN0002: │ @chakra-ui/switch@npm:1.0.0 [1a614] doesn't provide framer-motion (p69422), requested by @chakra-ui/checkbox
➤ YN0002: │ @chakra-ui/theme-tools@npm:1.0.0 [3e9d3] doesn't provide react (p542db), requested by @chakra-ui/utils
➤ YN0002: │ @chakra-ui/tooltip@npm:1.0.0 [1a614] doesn't provide react-dom (pdc6b1), requested by @chakra-ui/portal
➤ YN0002: │ @endemolshinegroup/cosmiconfig-typescript-loader@npm:3.0.2 [5deea] doesn't provide typescript (p88564), requested by ts-node
➤ YN0002: │ @examples-action-listener/counter@workspace:examples/action-listener/counter doesn't provide jest (p780f7), requested by jest-watch-typeahead
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/authentication-with-extrareducers@workspace:examples/query/react/authentication-with-extrareducers provides @types/react (pde12b) with version 18.0.12, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/authentication-with-extrareducers@workspace:examples/query/react/authentication-with-extrareducers provides react (pe1a51) with version 18.1.0, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/authentication@workspace:examples/query/react/authentication provides @types/react (p89bd6) with version 18.0.12, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/authentication@workspace:examples/query/react/authentication provides react (p2b7f5) with version 18.1.0, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0002: │ @examples-query-react/graphql-codegen@workspace:examples/query/react/graphql-codegen doesn't provide @types/node (p4d56f), requested by ts-node
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/graphql-codegen@workspace:examples/query/react/graphql-codegen provides @types/react (p2c07d) with version 18.0.12, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0002: │ @examples-query-react/graphql-codegen@workspace:examples/query/react/graphql-codegen doesn't provide graphql-tag (p714b3), requested by @graphql-codegen/typescript-rtk-query
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/graphql-codegen@workspace:examples/query/react/graphql-codegen provides react (pde925) with version 18.1.0, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/graphql@workspace:examples/query/react/graphql provides @types/react (p0bb41) with version 18.0.12, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/graphql@workspace:examples/query/react/graphql provides react (p7b674) with version 18.1.0, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/mutations@workspace:examples/query/react/mutations provides @types/react (pf429f) with version 18.0.12, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/mutations@workspace:examples/query/react/mutations provides react (p026b2) with version 18.1.0, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/optimistic-update@workspace:examples/query/react/optimistic-update provides @types/react (pefd01) with version 18.0.12, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/optimistic-update@workspace:examples/query/react/optimistic-update provides react (pa7deb) with version 18.1.0, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/pagination@workspace:examples/query/react/pagination provides @types/react (pb2ca8) with version 18.0.12, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/pagination@workspace:examples/query/react/pagination provides react (p46fd4) with version 18.1.0, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/prefetching-automatic-waterfall@workspace:examples/query/react/prefetching-automatic-waterfall provides @types/react (p4cb2c) with version 18.0.12, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/prefetching-automatic-waterfall@workspace:examples/query/react/prefetching-automatic-waterfall provides react (p13991) with version 18.1.0, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/prefetching-automatic@workspace:examples/query/react/prefetching-automatic provides @types/react (p4d582) with version 18.0.12, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/prefetching-automatic@workspace:examples/query/react/prefetching-automatic provides react (p09f45) with version 18.1.0, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/prefetching@workspace:examples/query/react/prefetching provides @types/react (p6dc77) with version 18.0.12, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ @examples-query-react/prefetching@workspace:examples/query/react/prefetching provides react (p16f06) with version 18.1.0, which doesn't satisfy what @chakra-ui/react and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0002: │ @reduxjs/toolkit@workspace:packages/toolkit doesn't provide @testing-library/dom (p0743d), requested by @testing-library/user-event
➤ YN0060: │ @reduxjs/toolkit@workspace:packages/toolkit provides eslint (p62c44) with version 7.28.0, which doesn't satisfy what eslint-config-react-app and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0002: │ @reduxjs/toolkit@workspace:packages/toolkit doesn't provide react-dom (pbde47), requested by @testing-library/react
➤ YN0002: │ @reduxjs/toolkit@workspace:packages/toolkit [a9ce6] doesn't provide @testing-library/dom (p577e8), requested by @testing-library/user-event
➤ YN0060: │ @reduxjs/toolkit@workspace:packages/toolkit [a9ce6] provides eslint (p6195a) with version 7.28.0, which doesn't satisfy what eslint-config-react-app and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0002: │ @reduxjs/toolkit@workspace:packages/toolkit [a9ce6] doesn't provide react-dom (p3669a), requested by @testing-library/react
➤ YN0002: │ @reduxjs/toolkit@workspace:packages/toolkit [f93a7] doesn't provide @testing-library/dom (pff99c), requested by @testing-library/user-event
➤ YN0060: │ @reduxjs/toolkit@workspace:packages/toolkit [f93a7] provides eslint (pa91f4) with version 7.28.0, which doesn't satisfy what eslint-config-react-app and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0002: │ @reduxjs/toolkit@workspace:packages/toolkit [f93a7] doesn't provide react-dom (p63f33), requested by @testing-library/react
➤ YN0060: │ @rtk-query/codegen-openapi@workspace:packages/rtk-query-codegen-openapi provides babel-jest (p51bdb) with version 26.6.3, which doesn't satisfy what ts-jest requests
➤ YN0002: │ @rtk-query/oazapfts-patched@npm:3.6.0-2 doesn't provide openapi-types (p08ecc), requested by @apidevtools/swagger-parser
➤ YN0002: │ docs@workspace:docs doesn't provide graphql (p08aca), requested by graphql-request
➤ YN0002: │ docs@workspace:docs doesn't provide next (p53ee4), requested by next-redux-wrapper
➤ YN0002: │ docs@workspace:docs doesn't provide react (p00b31), requested by formik
➤ YN0002: │ docs@workspace:docs doesn't provide react (pfc6f5), requested by next-redux-wrapper
➤ YN0002: │ docs@workspace:docs doesn't provide react-redux (pf67eb), requested by next-redux-wrapper
➤ YN0002: │ docs@workspace:docs doesn't provide redux (p272bc), requested by @manaflair/redux-batch
➤ YN0002: │ docs@workspace:docs doesn't provide redux (p16155), requested by redux-persist
➤ YN0002: │ eslint-config-react-app@npm:7.0.1 [5a722] doesn't provide @babel/plugin-syntax-flow (pa22cf), requested by eslint-plugin-flowtype
➤ YN0002: │ eslint-config-react-app@npm:7.0.1 [5a722] doesn't provide @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx (p1bbf5), requested by eslint-plugin-flowtype
➤ YN0002: │ eslint-config-react-app@npm:7.0.1 [74590] doesn't provide @babel/plugin-syntax-flow (p898ac), requested by eslint-plugin-flowtype
➤ YN0002: │ eslint-config-react-app@npm:7.0.1 [74590] doesn't provide @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx (p7d3b0), requested by eslint-plugin-flowtype
➤ YN0002: │ react-dev-utils@npm:12.0.1 doesn't provide typescript (p59348), requested by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0002: │ react-dev-utils@npm:12.0.1 doesn't provide webpack (p1012e), requested by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0060: │ rtk-monorepo@workspace:. provides eslint (p88204) with version 7.28.0, which doesn't satisfy what eslint-config-react-app and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ website@workspace:website provides react (p3b914) with version 18.1.0, which doesn't satisfy what @docusaurus/core and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ website@workspace:website provides react (pe296a) with version 18.1.0, which doesn't satisfy what @docusaurus/preset-classic and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ website@workspace:website provides react-dom (p17183) with version 18.1.0, which doesn't satisfy what @docusaurus/core and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0060: │ website@workspace:website provides react-dom (p6da37) with version 18.1.0, which doesn't satisfy what @docusaurus/preset-classic and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0000: │ Some peer dependencies are incorrectly met; run yarn explain peer-requirements <hash> for details, where <hash> is the six-letter p-prefixed code
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 497ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 762ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-android-arm64@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-darwin-arm64@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-freebsd-64@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-freebsd-arm64@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-linux-32@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-linux-64@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-linux-arm64@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-linux-arm@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-linux-mips64le@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-linux-ppc64le@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-netbsd-64@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-openbsd-64@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-sunos-64@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-windows-32@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-windows-64@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ esbuild-windows-arm64@npm:0.13.12 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 1s 382ms
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 2s 817ms
```

I found an article that is talking about a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61908394/when-running-yarn-install-what-does-it-mean-when-a-module-doesnt-provide-anoth). I'm not sure if this is an actual issue with the dependencies in the library or something I'm doing wrong. Can someone send me setup instructions for the redux toolkit project?

Comment: The stuff you are showing here doesn't have to do anything with Redux Toolkit. Tbh., I'm not even sure it is an error or just some message - you probably have cut off a lot of significant information with that screenshot.

Comment: OK @phry I've added the full terminal log and just so you know nothing gets installed in the `node_modules` folder. So even though these may not be errors something isn't working correctly.

Comment: `Done with warnings." None of this is an error, you can just start working with it. You might notice some peerDependencies missing once you compile code, (hence the warnings) and then you will have to install those - but for now is might also just work.